# Javascript Add Custom active Class inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have two loop like below you can see and need to add a custom **active-*numberHere*** class to the first image of each div with a specified number.
for example, if div class number is **img-4** so add class **active-4** to first img tag.

But I have some problems in code that you can see in the attached image.
in the first div image have the correct class.

 but in other div image have extra active like **active-4 active-3** and ...!

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```js
// LOOP Create Image Div 
let numDiv = 5;
for (k = 0; k < numDiv; k++) {

    //Add div area inside Div(products)
    let imgPart = `<div class="img-${k} shoe-part"> </div>`;
    document.querySelector(".products").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", imgPart);
    
    
// LOOP Create Image List Inside Divs 
    let numImg = 3;
    for (j = 0; j < numImg; j++) {
    
        //Add Image List Inside Above Div(shoe-part)
        let imgList = `<img class="res-img" src="img/image-${k}.png">`;
        document.querySelector(".shoe-part").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", imgList);
    }
$('.shoe-part img:first-child').addClass(`active-${k}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="products">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simple way to do this by jquery is to use `html()` and `prepend()` or `append()`
- for add class you can use a simple if statement inside the loop

```js
// LOOP Create Image Div 
let numDiv = 5;
for (k = 0; k < numDiv; k++) {

    //Add div area inside Div(products)
    var DivPart = `<div class="img-${k} shoe-part"></div>`;
    
    
// LOOP Create Image List Inside Divs 
    let numImg = 3;
    let ImgPart = '';
    for (j = 0; j < numImg; j++) {
        //Add Image List Inside Above Div(shoe-part)
        var AddClass = (j === 0) ? 'active-'+k : ''; // shorthand if statement to add the class only when j = 0
        ImgPart += `<img class="res-img ${AddClass}" src="img/image-${k}.png">`;  // add all the images in the valriable ImgPart by using += it means sum/combine/addto
    }
    DivPart = $(DivPart).html(ImgPart); // update DivPart with the whole div with images in it
    $('.products').prepend(DivPart); // prepend the DivPart to the product div
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="products">

</div>
```